# What exactly does the -p switch do for Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

From the manual:

```
---------------------------
Notepad++ Command Argument Help
---------------------------
Usage :

notepad++ [--help] [-multiInst] [-noPlugin] [-lLanguage] [-LlangCode] [-nLineNumber] [-cColumnNumber] [-pPosition] [-xLeftPos] [-yTopPos] [-nosession] [-notabbar] [-ro] [-systemtray] [-loadingTime] [-alwaysOnTop] [-openSession] [-r] [-qnEasterEggName | -qtText | -qfCntentFileName] [-qSpeed1|2|3] [-quickPrint] [filePath]

--help : This help message
-multiInst : Launch another Notepad++ instance
-noPlugin : Launch Notepad++ without loading any plugin
-l : Open file or display ghost typing with syntax highlighting of choice
-L : Apply indicated localization, langCode is browser language code
-n : Scroll to indicated line on filePath
-c : Scroll to indicated column on filePath
-p : Scroll to indicated position on filePath
-x : Move Notepad++ to indicated left side position on the screen
-y : Move Notepad++ to indicated top position on the screen
-nosession : Launch Notepad++ without previous session
-notabbar : Launch Notepad++ without tabbar
-ro : Make the filePath read only
-systemtray : Launch Notepad++ directly in system tray
-loadingTime : Display Notepad++ loading time
-alwaysOnTop : Make Notepad++ always on top
-openSession : Open a session. filePath must be a session file
-r : Open files recursively. This argument will be ignored
     if filePath contain no wildcard character
-qn : Launch ghost typing to display easter egg via its name
-qt : Launch ghost typing to display a text via the given text
-qf : Launch ghost typing to display a file content via the file path
-qSpeed : Ghost typing speed. Value from 1 to 3 for slow, fast and fastest
-quickPrint : Print the file given as argument then quit Notepad++
filePath : file or folder name to open (absolute or relative path name)

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

If -n means the line and -c means the column, then what is a "position" (-p), if not the combination of line + column? I don't get it. What does it refer to?

Comment: *what is a "position" (-p)* It is a SYMBOL NUMBER whith the cursor must be placed after. Standard Windows new line is counted as 2 chars (<CR> and <LF>).

Comment: Not quite sure but I think it is the position of a character in a file, counting from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This parameter allows to position the cursor to a certain character position.

If you position the cursor at the wanted position in the file
and select all characters from the current cursor position to the start
of the file using
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>home</kbd>,
then the status bar will say "Sel: numchars|numrows".

The `numchars` number, when used with the parameter `-p`, will open the
file and position the cursor at the indicated position.

The command should be written as:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -p<numchars> file-path
```